# Ordered Lists Inside ShieldUI Accordion

Tags: shieldui

Is it possible to include an ordered list inside a ShieldUI accordion?  Including one seems to break my accordion; I'm hoping there is some sort of flag or work around to get ordered lists working.

```html
<div class='accordion-container'>
    <h2>Delivery Instructions</h2>
    <ul id='accordion'>
        <li>
            <h2>Vehicle Delivery to Media / Client</h2>
            <p>Accordion 1</p>
            <li>Header
                <ol>
                    <li>One</li>
                    <li>Two</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Delivery to Airport</h2>
            <p>Accordion 2</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can someone from Shield UI confirm whether ordered lists can be made to work in an accordion or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in a `DIV`, like this:

```
  <div class='accordion-container'>
    <h2>Delivery Instructions</h2>
    <ul id='accordion'>
        <li>
            <h2>Vehicle Delivery to Media / Client</h2>
            <p>Accordion 1</p>
            <li>
                <h2>Header</h2>
                <div>
                    <ol>
                        <li>One</li>
                        <li>Two</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Delivery to Airport</h2>
            <p>Accordion 2</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you Vladimir, I will give that a try!